# Complexity of property of being vertex-transitive resp. of being a Cayley graph

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, cayley-graphs

Suppose I gave you a finite graph, and asked you whether it was vertex-transitive. How hard is that algorithmically?

The second question is: suppose I gave you a vertex transitive finite graph, and asked you whether it was a Cayley graph. How hard is that?

Comment: This question seems relevant: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14106/complexity-of-recognizing-vertex-transitive-graphs

Comment: @Arnaud: "relevant" is putting it mildly, it seems essentially identical, BUT even though there is an accepted answer, the question is not answered in any substantial way. Maybe the moderators can weigh in on what the right thing is...

Comment: Is there any reason to expect that this would be easier than the general graph automorphism/isomorphism problem?

Comment: @DerekHolt Vertex transitive graphs have a lot of extra structure, so certainly on a heuristic level one might think that if the answer is "no" (to vertex transitivity), then there would be some easy spectral (say) certificate. Also, one might ask: if all the degree sequences are equal, then is the graph vertex transitive (I assume the answer is "no", but one probably has to wake up pretty early in the morning to find a counterexample...)

Comment: This reminded me on the construction of the graph that gave Sarnak, Philips and Lubotzky. They constructed Ramanujan graph. The graph they constructed is vertex transitive and it's definition uses Cayley graphs. If a graph is vertex transitive then the trace formula for graphs is easier. Maybe you should look in the book of Davidoff, Sarnak and Valette and see the proof that the graph $X^{p,q}$ is vertex transitive.

Comment: I would be totally astonished if there was a better way of detecting vertex-transitivity than computing the automorphism group of the graph. All attempts at finding spectral or other combinatorial invariants that can distinguish graphs with big groups from the others have foundered, usually in the murky waters of strongly regular graphs where all the graphs "look the same" but have wildly different groups.

Comment: @alem: The proof that the Ramanujan graph $X^{p,q}$ is vertex transitive is an immediate consequence of the fact that it is defined as a Cayley graph. The difficult thing is to establish the spectral gap.

Comment: @Igor Rivin: It is not at all clear that large vertex-transitive graphs have a lot of extra structure vis-a-vis regular graphs. For what my opinion's worth, I expect that graph isomorphism is equivalent to isomorphism of vertex-transitive graphs. On the other hand deciding if a graph has a fixed-point free automorphism of order two is NP-hard, and so deciding if a vertex-transitive graph is Cayley may well be NP-complete.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil your opinion is worth a lot :) Is it easy to construct a (connected) graph where every vertex has the same degree sequence but is not vertex transitive? (nothing leaps to mind, but then, I haven't thought about it that much).

Comment: @Igor Rivin: see the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112818/generating-a-random-cubic-graph-with-uniform-probability-or-less for an algorithm that generates cubic graphs with uniform probability. To get small asymmetric cubic graphs, take a tree where all vertices have valency one or three and then draw a cycle through the vertices of valency one. The resulting graphs are planar and it easy to choose the tree so the graph constructed is not vertex transitive. Taking a cycle on $2n$ vertices and adding a perfect matching works too.

Comment: As far as I am aware, nothing more is known than is mentioned in these comments. There is another problem suggested: given a transitive permutation group, determine if it has a regular subgroup. Some work has been done on it, but I don't think it is solved.